# Overwriting a key binding profile with WoW add-on Binder

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am using Binder which is available here:

http://wow.curseforge.com/addons/binder/

My problem is, sometimes I update key bindings. I cannot seem to find a way to update a profile to use my new keybinding. If I hit `apply` on an existing key binding profile, it doesn't save/update, it merely loads the profile in the state it was created in.

Is there a solution to updating an existing profile if I add new key binds using Binder? If there isn't, is there a better add-on for managing different keybindings? I like to switch binds depending on what spec I am playing for my character. Usually there is a PvP spec and a PvE spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite action bar/keybind add-on is [Bartender](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/bartender4).  I don't particularly like the default Blizzard action bar, and this changes it for the better in my opinion.  If you don't want to change how it looks or its layout, I think Bartender has an option to keep it mostly the same.  It's been so long since I've changed that aspect of my UI that I'm not entirely sure though.  However, Bartender does an amazing job with keybinds and saves the profiles by character and talent specialization.  This is amazing when you switch specs and don't have to spend any time messing around with action bars.

Comment: I had no clue Bartender remembers keybindings?? Where is that done? I'll go confirm and mark this as the right answer if it does indeed do this.